# How to configure Spring Webclient to be able to toggle between proxy and nonproxy requests?

Tags: java, spring, http, proxy

I am using a spring WebClient class to make connections to different endpoints. Some endpoints require me to use a proxy to access that endpoint from my host. How can I configure my Spring webclient to be able to toggle between using a proxy connection and a default connection?

I have tried using System.setProperty("https.proxyHost") to set my proxies but it seems that the Spring Webclient is not utilizing the system properties for its connection.

Below is how I am current connecting to the proxy using the WebClient. Is there a way for me to rebuild the webclient using a different clientConnector or switch between proxy mode and non-proxy mode using the same Webclient?

```
ReactorClientHttpConnector connector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(options -> options.httpProxy(addressSpec -> { return addressSpec.host(this.proxyHost).port(Integer.parseInt(this.proxyPort)); }));
this.webClient = WebClient.builder().clientConnector(connector).build();
```